# windows 10 on mac + opencv + python,open the video but the frame is not displayed all the time

Tags: python, opencv, video-capture

Environment ：windows10 on mac，python3.6，opencv3.3

Problem：
The code can run rightly on the windows 7 + python 3.5， the window and the frame of the video display rightly.
But the same code can appear the window all the time，but the frame can not display rightly sometimes，sometimes the frame can be displayed normally.
And the output of the  variable ： ‘frame’ sometimes is ‘0’，while the right output should not be ‘0’：

```
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
ret, frame = cam.read()
print(frame)
```

The video can be opened normally when i have the Video phone call with my friend on the windows 10 of the mac.

Is the reason of the Camera drive of the mac run the windows 10？

Comment: the size of the memory is 4g，and the Available memory is 2g.

Comment: There is information missing from your question. How are you running Windows on a Mac - **Parallels**? **VMware**? **VirtualBox**? How is the camera connected and what camera is it?